# Remove records from Mongo DB 3.0.15 with multiple where condition

Tags: mongodb

How to remove records from mongo db with multiple "or" condition.

I have tryed

```
db.test.remove({"name":"a"},{"name" : "b"})
```

but it works on first condition only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $or operator like

```
db.test.remove({ $or: [ { "name": "a" }, { "name" : "b" } ] })
```

Comment: Thanks ! only rounded brackets was missing

Answer (score 1):

you can use : `db.test.remove{ $or: [ { "name": "a" }, { "name" : "b" } ] }`

The $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more  and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the . The $or has the following syntax:

```
{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

Comment: thanx for help.

Comment: only rounded brackets was missing

Answer (score 1):

Exact answer is:

```
db.test.remove({ $or: [ { "name": "a" }, { "name" : "b" } ] })
```